# How to read CSV file content and find out between based on string value in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have 1 data file 'file1.csv' with two columns data and need to read file content and find out the between rows based on first column string values 'finance & total' and similarly 'marketing & total'. Script should find 'finance' and 'finance total' then get the between (A,B,D,H) records And script should find 'marketing' and 'marketing total' then get the between (C,E,G) records. I don't want to get records before 'Finance' and after 'Marketing Total' string.

Also need to skip lines where 2nd or 3rd fields have nan string.

I tried with below code but not getting expected output.

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line == "finance" ]]; then
        echo $line >> output.csv
    else
        echo ""
    fi
done < file1.csv

file1.csv:
Departments Accounts  ##Header
Monthwise data        ##Sub Header
IT,Amount
P,20
q,30
IT Total,50
Finance,Amount
A,20
B,30
D,60
H,50
Finance Total,160
<Empty space>
Marketing,Amount
C,40
E,10
G,60
Marketing Total,110
HR,amount
X,20
Y,50
Z,10
```

Expected Output:

```
department,name,amount
Finance,A,20
Finance,B,30
Finance,D,60
Finance,H,50
Marketing,C,40
Marketing,E,10
Marketing,G,60
```

Expected output should be stored in output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Simple explanation would be, setting comma as FS, OFS for all lines and print heading in BEGIN section itself. Then in main program, check different conditions and print the values accordingly. NOTE this program will exit once it finds `Marketing Total` as per OP's mention.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  print "department,name,amount"
}
/Marketing Total/                          { exit                  }
/Finance Total/ || ($2=="nan" || $3=="nan"){ next                  }
/Finance,Amount/ || /Marketing,Amount/     { found=1;first=$1;next }
found                                      { print first,$0        }
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** in case nan value needs to be compared as case in-sensitive then try following code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  print "department,name,amount"
}
/Marketing Total/                                            { exit                  }
/Finance Total/ || (tolower($2)=="nan" || tolower($3)=="nan"){ next                  }
/Finance,Amount/ || /Marketing,Amount/                       { found=1;first=$1;next }
found                                                        { print first,$0        }
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Since OP has changed input a bit so edited code now.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, I have edited my input file data.  Can you please have a look and do the needful. I tried your program but I'm getting header column 'finance & amount' also in OP. Please note that my OP should be write into output file.

Comment: @Rummy, sure, I have already changed code, please do check once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, Still not getting expected OP. I want to get the records between string value 'Finance' & 'Finance Total'. Similarly 'Marketing & Marketing Total' and finally write into OP file.

Comment: @Rummy, I double checked even for your latest edited samples, This is even working with those, let me know.

Comment: @ Ravindersingh13, script should find 'finance' and 'finance total' then get the between (A,B,D,H) records And script should find 'marketing' and 'marketing total' then get the between (C,E,G) records.  I don't want to get records before 'Finance' and after  'Margeting Total' string.

Please see updated input file data.

Comment: @Rummy, could you please try `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==2||/Finance Total/||/Marketing Total/{if($0~/Marketing Total/){exit};first="";next} FNR==1{print "department,name,amount";next} /Finance/||/Marketing/{first=$1;next} {print first,$0}'  Input_file` once and let me know if this helps you? Once you confirm I will edit my answer then. Run this code in a single line please.

Comment: @Rummy, Sorry I can't believe it isn't working. With your shown samples it is working for me. Is your actual file same as shown samples, asking because you changed it 3 to 4 times, let me know.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, I'm getting before 'Finance' values i.e IT values. Please refer attached screenshot.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, Excellent and Thanks a lot. Perfectly working. I need one more , how to handle if we get 'nan' values (sometimes we will receive input file which would have space between 'Finance Total' & 'Marketing,Amount') . attached the screenshot.

Comment: @Rummy, yayyy I am happy to help. Could you please do update your question with complete details(like you want to skip nan which you mentioned now), try `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";print "department,name,amount"} /Marketing Total/{exit} /Finance Total/ || ($2=="nan" || $3=="nan"){next} /Finance,Amount/ || /Marketing,Amount/{found=1;first=$1;next} found{print first,$0}'  Input_file` once for skipping nan and let me know, will update my answer then, cheers.

Comment: Now I'm getting only Marketing values. Please refer latest attached screenshot.

Comment: @Rummy, OLD comment has been removed check my previous comment OR edited code in answer now, it should work.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, Perfectly working !! Thanks a lot.